# Cosmosdb SQL how to list all containers?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-data-factory

How to list all containers here? I wanna use it in the "lookup" activity of Azure Data Factory.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Kyaka, It is not possible to list the containers using Lookup activity in Azure Data Factory as CosmosDB linked service needs a collection name to be passed.  You may try to call the REST endpoint - `https://{databaseaccount}.documents.azure.com/dbs/{db-id}/colls` from an Azure Function and use Azure Function Activity to get collections list.
[image]

You can also check for other alternatives of calling REST API from ADF like Web Activity based on your requirements.

Please refer to the documentation [List Collections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db/list-collections) for details.

Thanks