# Which template of Azure function is suited to implement a custom lookup activity in ADF( Azure Data Factory)

Tags: azure-functions, azure-data-factory

Because there is no activity can [get a list of containers of CosmosDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68905394/cosmosdb-sql-how-to-list-all-containers), so I have to implement it myself.

And I wanna get all containers and pass them to ForEach Activity, what I wanna do is like Lookup Activity. Now, I am confusing because there are so many types of Functions.

---

[image]

Comment: From what I gather from [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-azure-function-activity) you need an Http triggered function. It calls an rest endpoint.

Comment: how to pass dynamic content to the Azure function? HTTPS+POST body?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to use HTTP Trigger template.

[image]

Comment: how to pass dynamic content to the Azure function? HTTPS+POST body?

Answer (score 0):

Azure Function with HTTP trigger is not the ideal option, because you must configure DB in two places, (Azure Function and ADF linked services) or (ADF linked services and the input of Azure Function).

However, other triggers also need to configuring two places.